# How to get Windows Server CPU Metrics remotely from Unix Box?

Tags: windows, unix, monitoring, snmp

I have a set of of Windows Server  boxes and i am trying to collect metrics ( Cpu utlization ,  Memory , Disk utilizaion ) from those boxes through my Unix system.  I tried using SNMP method , but it seems mind boggling . Not only i have to collect all OIDs for metrics in Windows ( which is very hard to Google and snmpwalk gives you a hell lot of information which is very hard to decipher ) . Is there any other ingenious ways to collect performance metrics from these windows boxes. 
I did think of an alternative of running my own python scripts and send these metrics to unix boxes , but that seems unlikely for various reasons.  any new method will be appreciated .

Answer (score 2):

you have basically 2 options:

1, use Nagios Remote Execution Plugin on Windows servers installed which you can very simply query from your UNIX box:

http://www.miwi-dv.com/nrpent/

I'm using it in enterprise env. to monitor health status of Windows Server boxes from rehel5.

2, Try WBEM/WMI, it also works from unix box :

```
http://openwbem.sourceforge.net/#Features
```

There is also wmi-client for linux available , some blog describe how-tos:

http://blogs.balabit.com/2010/09/18/wmi-client-for-linux/

http://forums.cacti.net/viewtopic.php?t=29392

Comment: But for this do i have to run nrpent in my windows box and then push the metrics to nagios ? like a passive check ? that seems like a last resort . Is there any other way where i can get those metrics without running any script from windows side.

Comment: Yes, see second option.You run it on UNIX box, it will utilize RPC to contact windows (you need some credentials of course)